# Sum Multiple Columns when Not Equal to a Specific Value in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have 4 different IF(AND) statements in 4 different consecutive columns. I need to return the calculated values from each of these cells in a separate column.

Column J has the formula:
    =IF(AND($D4

Column K has:
    =IF(AND($D4>=$G4, $D4<=$H4),0.5*3.33,"-")

Column L has:
    =IF(AND($D4>=$H4, $D4<=$I4),0.75*3.33,"-")

Column M has:
    =IF(AND($D4>=$I4),3.33,"-")

My goal is to have the 5th Column (N) calculate the total of Columns J through M when they have a value and not a "-".

Comment: Your Column J formula appears incomplete.  Also, are you wanting to display the totals of Columns J - M or are you simply wanting to display what each of their values are; for example "0, 1.67, -, -"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I suspect that the following will achieve what you are trying to achieve:

```
=SUMIF(J1:M1,"<>-")
```

Essentially, this takes the range of the data you are looking at and adds it up where it is not equal to your marker of a non-value, "-".

Hope this helps.

Cheers!